# Copy object from a reference into a variable

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to copy an object from a reference (range or cell for example) to a variable?

The reason why I want to do this is because I have a huge macro that calculates a lot of things and uses many copy+paste operations and it loops over many cells and alters them. This does not perform very well at all, so I wanted to minimize the GUI operations and work in the background, this way I could have the whole result in an array which I paste to the GUI in the end. The problem is that I need the objects not just the value of the cells/ranges because I need also to alter other properties (e.g. size or color).

Comment: If your code is slow and you want to speed it up, try posting it...

Comment: @TimWilliams It is far too much code. And if my original question could get answered I will be able to fix it on my own.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but it's difficult to offer better-performing alternatives to what you're already doing without seeing exactly how you're doing it. You wouldn't need to post the whole thing, just a representative portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations like looping on individual cells are slow because of the overhead associated with each call to the object model. So the trick is to work with multiple cells in each call.
 For values you can get an array of values from a range of cells into a variant resulting in a 2-dimensional array, and then you can assign the array back to the range
 for formats you either need to use a conditional format for a large range of cells or copy a format and paste it to a large range of cells.

Comment: The problem is that I have to alter nearly each cell differently, depending on the data I have. So I wanted to get a copy of the cell-objects so I don't have to do anything in the GUI until the end where I paste all my cell-copies back into the originals.

Comment: You can use Range objects in VBA, but a range object is not really a copy of a range so will only be of limited use.  Don't know why you need to use the GUI: just do it all in VBA with Screenupdating and Automatic calculation switched off.

Comment: I tested the program with the options you mentioned. The calculation time went down from ~45s to ~35s. That's not bad for the start, thanks.